# Typescript (react)t: infer generics in object values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types

Consider the following snippet:

```js
// index.ts
interface Component<P extends object = {}> {
  load(): { default: React.ComponentType<P> }
  props: P
}

const components: { [key: string]: Component } = {
  component1: {
    load: () => import('SomeComponent'),
    props: {
      importantValue: '12345',
    },
  },
  component2: {
    load: () => import('SomeComponent'),
    props: {
      stuff: 'should not compile',
    },
  },
}
```

```
// SomeComponent.tsx
interface Props {
  importantValue: string
}

export default function(props: Props) {
  /* ... */
}
```

So as you can see what I would like is to make typescript infer the generic type `P` from the component's props in the `components` object. Unfortunately, both entries compile without errors, which means wrong props may be passed to the component during runtime. I wouldn't like to import the `Props` interface and write `component1: {...} as Component<Props>` because not only is this less readable, but it will also require doubling the files for each component just to declare its props there, because if I import them directly from the `.tsx` file, that will break the whole point of the dynamic import. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but variables do not have enough inference behavior to achieve this. Using a function we can achieve this.

```
interface Component<P extends object = {}> {
    load(): Promise<{ default: React.ComponentType<P> }> // Promise here 
    props: P
}

function define<T extends Record<keyof T, object>>(o: { [P in keyof T]: Component<T[P]> }) {
    return o;
}

const components = define({
    component1: {
        load: () => import('./component'),
        props: {
            importantValue: '12345',
        },
    },
    component2: {
        load: () => import('./otherComponent'),
        props: {
            value: '12345',
        },
    },
    component3: {
        load: () => import('./component'), // error here 
        props: {
            stuff: 'should not compile',
        },
    },
})
```